# Four-dimensional generalization of the equation $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$

Tags: electromagnetism

In "The electrodynamics of moving dielectrics" (p. 262) Landau and Lifshitz have defined four-tensors and four-vector

$F^{\mu \nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-E_x&-E_y&-E_z\\
E_x&0&-B_z&B_y\\
E_y&B_z&0&-B_x\\
E_z&-B_y&B_x&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$H^{\mu \nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-D_x&-D_y&-D_z\\
D_x&0&-H_z&H_y\\
D_y&H_z&0&-H_x\\
D_z&-H_y&H_x&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$u^{\mu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}},&\frac{\vec{v}}{c\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}
\end{pmatrix}$

Then they write

> From this four-vector and the four-tensors $F^{\mu \nu}$ and $H^{\mu \nu}$ we form combinations which become $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{D}$ in a medium at rest. These combinations are the four-vectors $F^{\lambda \mu}u_{\mu}$ and $H^{\lambda \mu}u_{\mu}$; for $\vec{v} = 0$ their time components are zero and their space components are $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{D}$ respectively. The four-dimensional generalization of the equation $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$ is therefore evidently
> $$ H^{\lambda \mu} u_{\mu} = \epsilon F^{\lambda \mu}u_{\mu} $$

How is that evident?

I understand that with the assumption $\vec{v} = 0$ that generalized equation gives us $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$. But couldn't that just be a lucky coincidence?

Or is the reasoning something along these lines: "We found this equation, it gives good results, all the experiments work with that too, so it's probably right." ?

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\vec{D}=\epsilon\vec{E}$ in a medium at rest, assuming Einstein's principle of relativity to hold not only for Newtonian mechanics but for Maxwell's electrodynamics as well. Landau and Lifshitz manage to express this in a *manifestly covariant* way (as one says) as $H^{\lambda\mu}u_\mu=\epsilon F^{\lambda\mu}u_\mu$. Equations of the same form will then automatically be valid in all other inertial frames, since both sides of the equation transform as contravariant four-vectors under the Lorentz group.